# Place dynamic marking under bar line (move dynamics horizontally)

Tags: lilypond

I want to create a crescendo that extends over two measures.

The following code

```
\relative c'
{
    c4\pp\< c4 c4 c4 | c1\ff
}
```

compiles to

[image: Stupid FF. Position yourself further to the right!]

which is almost what I want. However, I would like the ff markings to appear further to the right, directly under the very next bar line, to indicate that the last whole tone should have a gradual increase in volume as well.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use ***[spacer rests](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.16/Documentation/notation/expressive-marks-attached-to-notes#index-multiple-dynamic-marks-on-one-note)*** to "move" the *fortissimo* to the end of the second bar:

```
\relative c'
{
    c4\pp\< c4 c4 c4 |
    << c1 { s2. s4\ff } >>
}
```

This results in:

[image: Lilypond output]

Comment: Actually, this solution struck me first thing when I woke up this morning :) However, I was under the impression that whenever you mixed simultaneous notes of different starting points and/or lengths, you had to specify a new voice. Seems like this isn't the case. I need to go back to the manuals again :P